# How do you connect the 'hamburgers' gem in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried doing their Ruby on Rails instruction for installation but when I included @import 'hamburgers' it doesn't know where to search for the file. So what I tried to do was copy the files from the '_sass/hamburgers' directory from the 'hamburgers' gem into my project.
[files inside the _sass/hamburgers directory pasted in my stylesheets folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kaK3.png)

Even after pasting the files in my project's stylesheet folder an error still shows up.
Error states

> Error: Undefined variable: "$hamburger-padding-y".
> on line 4:12 of app/assets/stylesheets/_base.scss
>
> > `padding: $hamburger-padding-y $hamburger-padding-x;`

If I understand correctly _base.scss is connected to hamburgers.scss so there shouldn't really be any issues. Hope to get some help!! :>

**EDIT:**
Here's my application.scss

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.scss, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
* vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
* compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
* files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
* It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
@import "hamburgers";
```

Here is also hamburgers.scss

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*!
 * Hamburgers
 * @description Tasty CSS-animated hamburgers
 * @author Jonathan Suh @jonsuh
 * @site https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers
 * @link https://github.com/jonsuh/hamburgers
 */

// Settings
// ==================================================
$hamburger-padding-x           : 15px !default;
$hamburger-padding-y           : 15px !default;
$hamburger-layer-width         : 40px !default;
$hamburger-layer-height        : 4px !default;
$hamburger-layer-spacing       : 6px !default;
$hamburger-layer-color         : #000 !default;
$hamburger-layer-border-radius : 4px !default;
$hamburger-hover-opacity       : 0.7 !default;
$hamburger-active-layer-color  : $hamburger-layer-color !default;
$hamburger-active-hover-opacity: $hamburger-hover-opacity !default;

// To use CSS filters as the hover effect instead of opacity,
// set $hamburger-hover-use-filter as true and
// change the value of $hamburger-hover-filter accordingly.
$hamburger-hover-use-filter   : false !default;
$hamburger-hover-filter       : opacity(50%) !default;
$hamburger-active-hover-filter: $hamburger-hover-filter !default;

// Types (Remove or comment out what you don’t need)
// ==================================================
$hamburger-types: (
 3dx,
 3dx-r,
 3dy,
 3dy-r,
 3dxy,
 3dxy-r,
 arrow,
 arrow-r,
 arrowalt,
 arrowalt-r,
 arrowturn,
 arrowturn-r,
 boring,
 collapse,
 collapse-r,
 elastic,
 elastic-r,
 emphatic,
 emphatic-r,
 minus,
 slider,
 slider-r,
 spin,
 spin-r,
 spring,
 spring-r,
 stand,
 stand-r,
 squeeze,
 vortex,
 vortex-r
) !default;

// Base Hamburger (We need this)
// ==================================================
@import "base";

// Hamburger types
// ==================================================
@import "types/3dx";
@import "types/3dx-r";
@import "types/3dy";
@import "types/3dy-r";
@import "types/3dxy";
@import "types/3dxy-r";
@import "types/arrow";
@import "types/arrow-r";
@import "types/arrowalt";
@import "types/arrowalt-r";
@import "types/arrowturn";
@import "types/arrowturn-r";
@import "types/boring";
@import "types/collapse";
@import "types/collapse-r";
@import "types/elastic";
@import "types/elastic-r";
@import "types/emphatic";
@import "types/emphatic-r";
@import "types/minus";
@import "types/slider";
@import "types/slider-r";
@import "types/spin";
@import "types/spin-r";
@import "types/spring";
@import "types/spring-r";
@import "types/stand";
@import "types/stand-r";
@import "types/squeeze";
@import "types/vortex";
@import "types/vortex-r";

// ==================================================
// Cooking up additional types:
//
// The Sass for each hamburger type should be nested
// inside an @if directive to check whether or not
// it exists in $hamburger-types so only the CSS for
// included types are generated.
//
// e.g. hamburgers/types/_new-type.scss
//
// @if index($hamburger-types, new-type) {
//   .hamburger--new-type {
//     ...
//   }
// }
```

Comment: Does the file that you copied into our project declare the variable `$hamburger-padding-y`?

Comment: Assuming you were following these steps, what does your `application.scss` file look like? https://github.com/jonsuh/hamburgers#install-for-ruby-on-rails

Comment: did you get the gem 'hamburgers' to work? When I tried it and then tried to start a rails server it breaks.

Comment: I got the hamburger animation to work in rails without installing the gem, if you want me to describe that (although it does not answer the question about the variables.)

Comment: @Chris Sure! That would be great!!

Comment: did you actually get the gem to work (e.g., not kill the server)?

Comment: @Chris It didn’t kill the server. The “website would just be replaced by the error view you typically get

Comment: what ruby/rails versions are you using? Also,a re you sure you added the gem hamburgers and not hamburger (note the s on the end difference)?

Comment: @Chris Will have to check tomorrow what ruby/rails version I’m on but I’m sure that the gem had an s at the end

Answer (score 0):

*Per the comments, the OP requested this info though it does not answer the primary question.*

Don't do any of the "ruby on rails" stuff from the official [documentation](https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers/).

Create `app/assets/stylesheets/hamburgers.css` and get the code from [here](https://github.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/blob/master/dist/hamburgers.css) (or just copy in the file). This is the `dist/hamburgers.css` file the documentation mentions.

In your application view (e.g., application.html.erb), in the `<head>` put in the stylesheet reference: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "hamburgers" %>`

Put in some html markup (get from the [documentation example here](https://github.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/blob/master/dist/example.html)). Also, be sure to put the `<script>` code from the example (it's at the end).

When I did this, I got a fresh rails site to work exactly the same as how the hamburger author's example.html works.

As to why you get that hamburger-padding-y error, I don't think you are supposed to need to put the css AND scss files. The yarn install combined with the rails gem is *probably* supposed to take care of this, but I couldn't recreate the error because I couldn't get a rails server to work if I install the gem (hamburgers, which resolved to v1.1.3). I was using Ruby 2.6.2 / Rails 6.0.3.3

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to separate the script in a different file and connect it with the html(application.html.erb)